# Send SMS using triggers and stored procedures from SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, triggers, sms-gateway

I written a trigger on `smslog` table

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[mytrigger]    
   ON  [dbo].[smslog]   
   AFTER INSERT    
AS   
   Declare @MobileNo int   
   Declare @smstext as varchar(300)   
Begin    
   set @MobileNo = ( select mobile from inserted)  
   set @smstext = (select smstext from inserted)  
   set @sResponse = 'test'
   Exec pr_SendSmsSQL @MobileNo, @smstext, @sResponse  
END
```

Stored procedure is

```
create procedure [dbo].[pr_SendSmsSQL] 
    @MobileNo varchar(12), 
    @smstext as varchar(300), 
    @sResponse varchar(1000) OUT 
as 
BEGIN 
   Declare @iReq int,@hr int 
   Declare @sUrl as varchar(500) 
   DECLARE @errorSource VARCHAR(8000)
   DECLARE @errorDescription VARCHAR(8000) 

   -- Create Object for XMLHTTP 
   EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP', @iReq OUT 

   print @hr 

   if @hr <> 0 
      Raiserror('sp_OACreate Microsoft.XMLHTTP FAILED!', 16, 1) 

   set @sUrl='http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?user=devendar&password=csx19csx&api_id=3360313&to=#MobNo#&text=#Msg#' 

   set @sUrl=REPLACE(@sUrl,'#MobNo#',@MobileNo) 
   set @sUrl=REPLACE(@sUrl,'#Msg#',@smstext) 

   print @sUrl 

   -- sms code start 
   EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @iReq, 'Open', NULL, 'GET', @sUrl, true 
   print @hr 

   if @hr <> 0 
      Raiserror('sp_OAMethod Open FAILED!', 16, 1) 

   EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @iReq, 'send' 
   select @iReq
   print @hr 

   if @hr <> 0 
   Begin 
       EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @iReq, @errorSource OUTPUT, @errorDescription OUTPUT

       SELECT [Error Source] = @errorSource, [Description] = @errorDescription

       Raiserror('sp_OAMethod Send FAILED!', 16, 1) 
   end 
else 
Begin
    EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @iReq,'responseText', @sResponse OUT 
    print @hr

    insert into send_log (Id, mobile, sendtext, response, created, createddate) 
    values(0, @MobileNo, @smstext, @sResponse, 'System', GETDATE())
end
end
```

I use clickatell gateway here please help me on this what is the issue

I am not able to send SMS when I insert a row into the `smslog` table

I used after insert in trigger and passed parameters to stored procedure to send SMS.

Please help me on this

Thanks in Advance
devendar

Comment: Hi Diego,  no error showing in sql server - its showing executed, but sms is not sending out.

Comment: is it possible to run url using stored procedure and is the above code is write or wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[mytrigger]    
   ON  [dbo].[smslog]   
   AFTER INSERT    
AS   
   Declare @MobileNo int   
   Declare @smstext as varchar(300)   
Begin    
   set @MobileNo = ( select mobile from inserted)  
   set @smstext = (select smstext from inserted)  
   set @sResponse = 'test'
   Exec pr_SendSmsSQL @MobileNo, @smstext, @sResponse  
END
```

Procedure

```
create procedure [dbo].[pr_SendSmsSQL] 
    @MobileNo varchar(12), 
    @smstext as varchar(300), 
    @sResponse varchar(1000) OUT 
as 
BEGIN 
   Declare @iReq int,@hr int 
   Declare @sUrl as varchar(500) 
   DECLARE @errorSource VARCHAR(8000)
   DECLARE @errorDescription VARCHAR(8000) 

   -- Create Object for XMLHTTP 
   EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP', @iReq OUT 

   print @hr 

   if @hr <> 0 
      Raiserror('sp_OACreate Microsoft.XMLHTTP FAILED!', 16, 1) 

   **set @sUrl='http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?user=devendar&password=csx19csx&api_id=3360313&to=#MobNo#&text=#Msg#'**
```

**
THe APi isnot working properly - remaining code is excellent it working in a great way
**

```
   set @sUrl=REPLACE(@sUrl,'#MobNo#',@MobileNo) 
   set @sUrl=REPLACE(@sUrl,'#Msg#',@smstext) 

   print @sUrl 

   -- sms code start 
   EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @iReq, 'Open', NULL, 'GET', @sUrl, true 
   print @hr 

   if @hr <> 0 
      Raiserror('sp_OAMethod Open FAILED!', 16, 1) 

   EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @iReq, 'send' 
   select @iReq
   print @hr 

   if @hr <> 0 
   Begin 
       EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @iReq, @errorSource OUTPUT, @errorDescription OUTPUT

       SELECT [Error Source] = @errorSource, [Description] = @errorDescription

       Raiserror('sp_OAMethod Send FAILED!', 16, 1) 
   end 
else 
Begin
    EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @iReq,'responseText', @sResponse OUT 
    print @hr

    insert into send_log (Id, mobile, sendtext, response, created, createddate) 
    values(0, @MobileNo, @smstext, @sResponse, 'System', GETDATE())
end
end
```