# SMS send from SQL

Tags: sql

is it possible to send sms through database without using third party URL...?

Comment: That would most certainly surprise me.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server I guess

Comment: What do you want? What have you tried?

Comment: Check this guys: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10088230/4610605

Answer (score 2):

Check out "[Send SMS using triggers and stored procedures from SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10088230/4610605)" !

Given that information there we can say that it is NOT possible without any third party URL/Service.